# service provider login oauth

Tags: oauth, cas

How can I log in a OAuth Consumer such as desktop application  using service provider credentials, for example facebook.
I need to configure login-webflow.xml in CAS too.

Answer (score 1):

For CAS server, you can enable two kinds of OAuth support : client and server. Take a look at the documentation : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/OAuth